# Importing Pythons Functions Script into another Python File?

Tags: python, function, import

I have this python assignment where I need to do the following:
You will create a file myFunctions.py, where you will define/write the functions below:

min(list) # returns min of a list
max(list) # returns max of a list
avg(list) # returns average of a list
sum(list) # returns sum of a list
abs(num) # returns absolute value of num
find(key,list)# returns true if key value is found in a list
isEven(number) # returns true/false if number is even
You will import myFunctions.py into a file testFunctions.py, where you will call/test each of the above functions.

So far, here's what I've got:
myFunctions.py:

```
from random import randint

x = randint(5,10)
aList = []
for i in range(0, x, 1):
    number = randint(1,7)
    aList.append(number)
    print(number, end=', ')

def min(aList):
    return min(aList)

def max(aList):
    return max(aList)

sum = 0
 def avg(aList):
sum = 0
for i in range(0,len(aList)):
    sum += aList
    return sum / len(aList)
def sum(aList):
    while True:
        return sum(aList)
        break
def abs(aList):
    return abs(aList[1])

def find(aList):
    x = aList.find()
    return x

def isEven(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

testFunctions.py:

```
import myFunctions
from myFunctions import max

from random import randint

x = randint(5,10)
aList = []
for i in range(0, x, 1):
    number = randint(1,7)
    aList.append(number)
    print(number, end=', ')

myFunctions.max(aList)
```

I'm stuck on the parameters of each function and how to use them in the other python file.Any tips?

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: Horrible instructions.  min/max/abs/sum/list already exist in Python and should not be used for new variable/function names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but if you want to access `aList` from `testFunctions`, you can do so as `myFunctions.aList`.

However, I think you are confusing the `aList` in the function definition (`def max(aList):...`) with the `aList` in `testFunctions`. You named them the same, but they are different (but related) things.

When you call `myFunctions.max(aList)` in `testFunctions` it is taking `aList` that you made directly above it in the same file and passing it to the function `max`. Within `max` whatever list is the input is given a local variable name `aList` regardless of the name of the variable when you called `max(aList)`. If you made a `bList` in `testFunctions` the behavior of the `max` function is the same because `aList` within the `max` function refers to whatever list max was given, not a specific list called `aList`.

It would probably help to rename one of your `aList`s to something different to avoid confusion.